# How to get model's field name in custom editor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm building my first custom editor template for a text area control.  My code so far is -

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<%= Html.TextAreaFor( Model => Model , 2, 30, 
     new { @class = "html", @placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark }) %>
```

It's not much so far, but it does work.  But we need to add a character counter field to show remaining number of characters that the user can type in.  I know how to do all the JavaScript to make this work.

So to keep naming system same, I'm going to add a control named ".charCounter" to display number of remaining characters left.  My problem is that I cannot figure out the correct syntax to be able to retrieve the field name for the model.

The final version will look something like (JavaScript omitted) -

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<dynamic>" %>
<%= Html.TextAreaFor( Model => Model , 2, 30, 
     new { @class = "html", @placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark }) %>
<span class="xxx">Remaining characters - 
     <input readonly type="text" name="<fieldName>.charCounter" />
</span>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could use `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix`, like this:

```
<input 
    readonly="readonly" 
    type="text" 
    name="<%= ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix %>.charCounter" 
/>
```

Answer (score 17):

I ran into an issue where the PropertyName wasn't returning the Model prefix eg Contact.FirstName.  I was able to have it return the HTML field Id using this:

```
@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("")
```

**Returns:**
Contact_FirstName

Respectively you can return the field name using:

```
@ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("")
```

**Returns:**

Contact.FirstName

Answer (score 4):

`ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName` works nicely in MVC3.

In razor:

```
<input readonly="readonly" type="text" name="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName">
```

Answer (score 3):

Getting just the model name/Id (e.g **BirthDate**):

```
ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName;
```

Getting the model name with prefixes for complex objects (e.g **Identity.Person.BirthDate**):

```
@Html.NameFor(m => Model);
```

or

```
ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
```

Getting the model Id with prefixes for complex objects (e.g **Identity_Person_BirthDate**):

```
@Html.IdFor(m => Model)
```

or

```
@Html.IdForModel()
```