# In a custom editor template, how do I access the field name I should use for the edit control?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, editortemplates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get model's field name in custom editor template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615541/how-to-get-models-field-name-in-custom-editor-template)

When outputting an edit control for a special type of entity, for example, let’s say a color or something:

```
@Html.EditorFor(product => product.Color)
```

I want this to output a drop-down list, so I tried to create a custom editor template that shall render such a drop-down. Here is what my template looks like so far:

```
@model MyProject.Models.Color
@using (var db = new MyProject.Models.DbContext())
{
    @Html.DropDownList(???,
        new SelectList(db.Colors, "Id", "Name", Model))
}
```

What do I have to put instead of the `???` — the parameter that specifies the HTML `name` attribute for the drop-down?

---

(For obvious reasons, it’s not just `"Color"`. Consider several invocations of the same edit template for *different* fields of the *same* type, e.g.:

```
@Html.EditorFor(product => product.InnerColor)
@Html.EditorFor(product => product.OuterColor)
```

Clearly, this needs to generate drop-downs with different names.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The drop-down list already receives the correct field name all by itself. Anything you pass into the `name` parameter gets *concatenated onto* the field name, preventing it from being recognised.

The correct solution is to pass the empty string:

```
@Html.DropDownList("", new SelectList(...))
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6615541/how-to-get-models-field-name-in-custom-editor-template) suggests to use

```
ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix
```

So the full code will be somthing like

```
@model MyProject.Models.Color
@using (var db = new MyProject.Models.DbContext())
{
    @Html.DropDownList(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix + "_Color",
        new SelectList(db.Colors, "Id", "Name", Model))
}
```